# Adding Backbone events to an object, not registering "on" event when modified

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I may possibly be misunderstanding the eventing system in Backbone, but when I try the following code nothing happens. Should it not fire some sort of change, update or reset event when I add a new property to my Backbone.Events extended object? Like it does with a model?

### Coffeescript:

```
data = items: {}

eventedData = _.extend data, Backbone.Events

# It has an on method!
console.log eventedData.on.length > 0

# Running on with everything I could imagine happening
eventedData.on 'update change reset add', () ->
  alert 'Yay!'

# Triggers nothing
eventedData.items.newthing = 'Testing'
```

The above code in a JSBin http://jsbin.com/qofad/1/edit

I tried using `object.set`, or applying it directly rather than in a subobject, but nowt. Any ideas?

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing the functionality of `.get` and `.set` and others in Views/Models/Collections with events.

This for example is how backbone would trigger a change event on a `.set`:

```
set: function(attr, value) {
  this.attributes[attr] = value;
  this.trigger('change:' attr, ...);
}
```

The code is a little more involved than that but that is what it is essentially doing. No magic there. Backbone doesn't have "magic" object observation stuff as you are expecting but that makes a lot of sense but goes out of the scope of answering the question.

Sorry I don't know how to write it in CoffeeScript and you have 2 errors in your jsbin, but here is an example in normal JavaScript:

```
var ItemModel = function() {
    this.items = {}; // It is important this is created in instance-scope.
    this.initialize();
};

_.extend(ItemModel.prototype, Backbone.Events, {
    initialize: function() {},

    set: function(attr, value, options) {
        options = options || {};
        var oldValue = this.items[attr];
        this.items[attr] = value;

        if (!options.silent) {
            this.trigger('change', attr, value, {
                oldValue: oldValue
            });
            this.trigger('change:' + attr, value, {
                oldValue: oldValue
            });
        }
    },

    get: function(attr) {
        return this.items[attr];   
    }
});

ItemModel.extend = Backbone.Model.extend;

var MyImplementationOfItem = ItemModel.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.on('change', this.onItemChange);   
    },

    onItemChange: function(attr, value, options) {
        alert(attr + ' changed to ' + value + ' from ' + options.oldValue);  
    }
});

var myImplementationOfItem = new MyImplementationOfItem();

// Wait 4s then trigger it.
setTimeout(function() {
    myImplementationOfItem.set('hello', 'world');
}, 2000);

setTimeout(function() {
    myImplementationOfItem.set('hello', 'universe');
}, 4000);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5jaeu/1/

Note that this is a simplified re-implementation of get and set already in Views/Models/Collections. You are encouraged to use those instead!

Comment: Thanks for answering- I assumed it would inherit the change events but I guess not. What would be a solution then if you don't mind me asking? Just fire obj.trigger() when adding the new property? Would I have to use `set()`? I guess whether I used set or just modified the object explicitly wouldn't matter if I were manually triggering the event anyway would it?

Comment: Yeah you would have to proxy through a `.set` I'll make an example now

Comment: Ah cheers for the edit- I'll have a proper look through it on Monday (it's beer o'clock!) and will respond/upvote/accept then. From a brief glance it's making me wonder whether to just model the data I need as a collection of models. And you can ignore the errors in the jsbin; it lints it as javascript rather than coffeescript! And vanilla js is fine of course, I just like syntactic sugar ;) Thanks again!

Comment: @MattFletcher no prob - yeah I recommend using backbone's collection and model for this stuff unless you have a really good reason not to. Enjoy the beers!

Comment: I got everything working just by using models and collections in the end. It's a shame because it would have been quite nice just to leverage the power of events on a plain object, but it's better doing it this way anyway as it makes everything a lot more robust. Thanks for the help Dominic!